# How to interpret Cox Proportional Hazards model output when running survival analysis in R?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I have begun studying survival analysis and am using R packages `survival` and `survminer`. Verbal descriptions of statistical concepts can be “sloppy” and I’m trying to understand these concepts using crystal-clear language. I’ve worked through a Cox Proportional Hazards model example using http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-proportional-hazards-model using univariate Cox regression and the lung cancer data provided in the “lung” dataset of the survival package. I am trying to interpret the `coxph()` output as illustrated below. Are my interpretations shown below, correct? And as asked below in brackets, how does one tell which variable is used as the baseline and which is the comparison variable? How can you tell from the below `coxph()` output that it is the female sex variable with the lower hazard rate?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the sex variable is a factor? Usually the coefficient in the output will be named as e.g. "male" so you know the baseline is female or vice versa. One of the two should be the baseline. Your interpretations are correct, and to your question of whether you can get any more information from the coefficient, the Cox model kind of skips making any statements about the form of the survival function, so the estimates can really only be interpreted as far as effects on the hazard

Comment: I would maybe add to your interpretation that the model makes the constraint of proportional hazards over time, so for example, if the estimate is for being male compared to a female baseline, then males have exp($\beta$) times the hazard of females in general, so at any point in time. This is unless you have time varying effects, which are valid but in which case you can't compare two general individuals anymore as the hazard ratio does not apply across all time

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the sex variable is a factor. The ouput image posted is from http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-proportional-hazards-model , but I ran it myself in R and get the same output `Call: coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)` with no indication of which is the baseline set and which is the comparison set.

Comment: I might try `lung$sex=ifelse(lung$sex==1,"male","female")` and then fit the model again using `coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ as.factor(sex), data = lung)` (as.factor might not even be needed) and just see what you get

Comment: OK that works and `as.factor()` isn't needed; also, the output row name is a little cleaner without using `as.factor()`. Note that this makes the female subset the baseline and the male subset presented as the comparison in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpretation of coefficients depends on how the predictor variables are coded. In this example, with `male = 1` and `female = 2`, the software will assume that the values are numeric.

On that basis, the coefficient for `sex` will be just what you would have for a continuous numeric predictor variable: the change in log-hazard per unit increase in the "numeric" `sex` variable. With only 2 possible values of the "numeric" `sex` variable, that unit increase is for the change from `male` to `female`. That's equivalent to having `male` as the reference level, and the coefficient being the extra log-hazard associated with `female`.

As comments suggest, you can resolve any ambiguity by explicitly coding `sex` as a factor. That allows you to choose the reference level. The R default when reporting coefficient values in that case is to append the specific non-reference level to the overall predictor name.

Even in that case, however, you have to be careful. The default "treatment" or "dummy" coding of factors in R is to treat the first level as the reference/baseline. I recall that SPSS (or some other software that I don't use) treats the last level as the reference instead. Also, even within R, you can choose [different types of coding](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/modules/coding-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-models/) for categorical predictors that will affect the interpretation of coefficients.

Comment: That works, and when running `coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ as.factor(sex), data = lung)`, while leaving the sex variables as numerics, the output correctly specifies that the coefficients et al apply to code = 2 for female; thus, it is made clear that female in this case is the comparison and male the baseline.

Comment: @Village.Idyot for completeness, your interpretations are OK. Be careful with terminology; "univariate" is now typically used to describe a single type of _outcome_, not a single predictor, with "multivariate" meaning different types of outcomes. I will, however, confess to having used "multivariate" to describe a multiple-predictor model in at least one publication.

Comment: Thanks! Are there terms currently in use for single and multiple predictors, respectively? In lieu of univariate/multivariate I used in my OP?

Comment: @Village.Idyot "single-predictor" versus "multiple-predictor" in general or, in the regression context with multiple predictors, "multiple regression."